# Показать блок один раз по скрипту

Tags: javascript, css

Как показать блок только один раз, руководствуясь скриптом ниже?
Обе кнопки призваны показать класс, в случае щелчка по ним, но нужно, чтобы выполнялось условие: если блок уже показан, то скрывать при нажатии на кнопку не надо.

```js
//Показать Форму заказать звонок
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".callmeform").click(function() {
       var element = document.querySelector(".call-form-wrap");
       if(element.classList.contains("show-block")) {
          element.classList.remove("show-block");
       } else {
          element.classList.add("show-block");
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.show-block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="callmeform">Показать</button>
<div class="call-form-wrap" style="display: none">
   Теперь меня видно, чувак. 
</div>

<button class="callmeform">Показать 2</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".callmeform").click(function() {
       var element = document.querySelector(".call-form-wrap");
       if(element.classList.contains("show-block")) {
         } else {
          element.classList.add("show-block");
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.show-block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="callmeform">Показать</button>
<div class="call-form-wrap" style="display: none">
   Теперь меня видно, чувак. 
</div>

<button class="callmeform">Показать 2</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Или так красивше:

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(".callmeform").click(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector(".call-form-wrap");
  element.classList.contains("show-block") ? "" : element.classList.add("show-block");      
});
});
```

```css
.show-block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="callmeform">Показать</button>
<div class="call-form-wrap" style="display: none">
   Теперь меня видно, чувак. 
</div>

<button class="callmeform">Показать 2</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если без хитрых замыслов, то можно так!

```js
//Показать Форму заказать звонок
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".callmeform").click(function() {
       var element = document.querySelector(".call-form-wrap");
       const isShow = element.classList.contains("show-block");
       if (isShow) return;
       if(isShow) {
          element.classList.remove("show-block");
       } else {
          element.classList.add("show-block");
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.show-block {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="callmeform">Показать</button>
<div class="call-form-wrap" style="display: none">
   Теперь меня видно, чувак. 
</div>

<button class="callmeform">Показать 2</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Без Jquery

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.callmeform')
const div = document.querySelector('.call-form-wrap')

btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', () => 
  div.style.display != 'none' ? false : div.style.display = 'block'
));
```

```html
<button class="callmeform">Показать</button>
<div class="call-form-wrap" style="display: none">
   Теперь меня видно, чувак. 
</div>
<button class="callmeform">Показать 2</button>
```